# Emacs X11 autocompletion (intellisense)

Tags: emacs, intellisense, x11

I use visual studio for day to day programming (read putting food in my mouth) but for personal programming (read c/c++ hacking) I use Emacs.

Right now I am doing a programming exercise involving the X11 API. I am continually referring to the programming API manual to find the signature of function calls.

What would be really nice would be if there was an emacs alternative to the visual studio intellisense. I know there is autocompletion for the language specifics.

Is there such an extension available to Emacs? Or if not, is there way of creating one, maybe using the language specifics mechanism already used for auto completion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out : http://cedet.sourceforge.net/intellisense.shtml if that would work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Check out autocomplete.el, combine it with CEDET and you've got yourself true drop-down box intellisense-style completions.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete
http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Cedet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CollectionOfEmacsDevelopmentEnvironmentTools) offers auto-completion for C++ etc., and is part of Emacs 23. You might also want to check out [Auto-Complete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete), which is what I use myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have [cedit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CollectionOfEmacsDevelopmentEnvironmentTools) installed, but frankly I never use it. But I'm not enamoured of intellisense either. You seem to like it, so you may like cedit as well.

You may also be interested in [VisEmacs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/visemacs/), which allows you to use Emacs as your editor under VisualStudio. That I use every day.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% auto completion, but you may also be interested in ETAGS, the CTAGS of emacs. http://ctags.sourceforge.net/

> Ctags generates an index (or tag) file of language objects found in source files that 
>   allows these items to be quickly and easily located by a text editor or other utility. 
>   A tag signifies a language object for which an index entry is available (or, alternatively,
>   the index entry created for that object).